# How do I stop indexing in Pycharm?

Tags: python, indexing, pycharm

I have a 2 simple projects with simple python scripts. No other users, no java, no databases, no deployment, nothing complicated at all. I've excluded both project folders. I've downloaded shared indexes, even though I see now that I don't need shared indexes, since I'm a lone programmer. I see from searching for answers online, that this issue has been a problem since 2016! I installed the latest PyCharm v2021.3.2. hoping that this bug was fixed. Nothing seems to work. I've let it index for HOURS!! I need to be able to run my scripts. I've been trying to correct this problem for a week and I'm out of time. My work project is now a week behind, and my client is getting angry with me and this is coming out of my pocket!